How to store org mode link containing full header path in description?
Assume
org-id-link-to-org-use-id t

File.org
* Header 1
** Subheader 1
*** Subheader 2
* Header 2

point at Subheader 2
(org-store-link nil) adds ID property and returns
"[[id:6d36e91c-e8de-456a-b1f3-a02a0447f45c][Subheader 2]]"

Sometimes (not always) it would be necessary to get instead:
"[[id:6d36e91c-e8de-456a-b1f3-a02a0447f45c][File.org::Header 1/Subheader 1/Subheader 2]]"

What would be the most optimal solution ? Thanks !
